# Print all methods defined in a ruby file

Tags: ruby, methods

I'd like to print all free methods (outside of classes or modules).

Consider this example.

```rb
def func_a
end

def func_b
end

puts "All methods: #{the_magic_method.join}"
```

The output should contain my two methods.

---

I know, for classes (e.g. string) I could use *String.methods*.

Comment: There are no "free" methods. Every method belongs to an object.

Comment: In your example, would you consider `puts` a "free method"?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this but you could use the `method_added` hook provided by the `Module` class [Module#method_added](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-method_added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When free functions are defined in Ruby, they become private methods on the Object class. there is a default instance of the Object class which is the self context for ruby code outside of a class block, called the main instance.

```
initial_methods = private_methods

def func_a
end

def func_b
end

final_methods = private_methods
new_methods = final_methods - initial_methods


puts "#{new_methods.join}"
```

Comment: To my surprise, this doesn't work (tested in ruby 2.6.5 and 2.4.1). The diff is empty. `method(:func_a)` is there, but `methods.include?(:func_a)` is `false`. Very weird...

Comment: yes same, i tested it initially in pry and it was working there but that environment must be different somehow. I need to revise this answer

Comment: are you sure they are private methods? because I see `methods` includes it but not `private_methods`

Comment: well, i had different results running under IRB and PRY, where they did land up under methods. When a file is fed to an interpreter, they showed only under private_methods

Answer (score -1):

```
User.methods(false)
```

return only the methods defined within class.

Comment: Not what was asked.